# More about MySQL group and aggregate for several consecutive days

Tags: mysql

The table is designed to contain pets and their activity data, e.g, sleep time and exercise time. The table definition is provided below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST_ACTIVITY(
    pet_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    simple_sleep_time INT(11),
    deep_sleep_time INT(11),
    mild_movement_time INT(11),
    moderate_movement_time INT(11),
    severe_movement_time INT(11),
    start_time INT(11) NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (pet_id, start_time, date)
) ENGINE=INNODB
```

The following data is inserted to the table.

```
INSERT INTO TEST_ACTIVITY 
(pet_id, simple_sleep_time, deep_sleep_time, mild_movement_time, moderate_movement_time, severe_movement_time, start_time, date) 
VALUES
(100,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-10'),
(100,  2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-10'),
(100,  3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 60, '2015-03-10'),
(100,  4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 90, '2015-03-10'),
(100,  5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 120, '2015-03-10'),
(100,  6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 150, '2015-03-10'),
(100,  7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-11'),
(100,  8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-11'),
(100,  9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 60, '2015-03-11'),
(100,  10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 90, '2015-03-11'),
(100,  11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 120, '2015-03-11'),
(100,  12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 150, '2015-03-11'),
(100,  13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-12'),
(100,  14, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-12'),
(100,  15, 1, 1, 1, 1, 60, '2015-03-12'),
(100,  16, 1, 1, 1, 1, 90, '2015-03-12'),
(100,  17, 1, 1, 1, 1, 120, '2015-03-12'),
(100,  18, 1, 1, 1, 1, 150, '2015-03-12'),
(100,  19, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-13'),
(100,  20, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-13'),
(100,  21, 1, 1, 1, 1, 60, '2015-03-13'),
(100,  22, 1, 1, 1, 1, 90, '2015-03-13'),
(100,  23, 1, 1, 1, 1, 120, '2015-03-13'),
(100,  24, 1, 1, 1, 1, 150, '2015-03-13'),
(101,  25, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-10'),
(101,  26, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-10'),
(101,  27, 1, 1, 1, 1, 60, '2015-03-10'),
(101,  28, 1, 1, 1, 1, 90, '2015-03-10'),
(101,  29, 1, 1, 1, 1, 120, '2015-03-10'),
(101,  30, 1, 1, 1, 1, 150, '2015-03-10'),
(101,  31, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-11'),
(101,  32, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-11'),
(101,  33, 1, 1, 1, 1, 60, '2015-03-11'),
(101,  34, 1, 1, 1, 1, 90, '2015-03-11'),
(101,  35, 1, 1, 1, 1, 120, '2015-03-11'),
(101,  36, 1, 1, 1, 1, 150, '2015-03-11'),
(101,  37, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-12'),
(101,  38, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-12'),
(101,  39, 1, 1, 1, 1, 60, '2015-03-12'),
(101,  40, 1, 1, 1, 1, 90, '2015-03-12'),
(101,  41, 1, 1, 1, 1, 120, '2015-03-12'),
(101,  42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 150, '2015-03-12'),
(101,  43, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-13'),
(101,  44, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-13'),
(101,  45, 1, 1, 1, 1, 60, '2015-03-13'),
(101,  46, 1, 1, 1, 1, 90, '2015-03-13'),
(101,  47, 1, 1, 1, 1, 120, '2015-03-13'),
(101,  48, 1, 1, 1, 1, 150, '2015-03-13'),
(102,  49, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-10'),
(102,  50, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-10'),
(102,  51, 1, 1, 1, 1, 60, '2015-03-10'),
(102,  52, 1, 1, 1, 1, 90, '2015-03-10'),
(102,  53, 1, 1, 1, 1, 120, '2015-03-10'),
(102,  54, 1, 1, 1, 1, 150, '2015-03-10'),
(102,  55, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-11'),
(102, 56, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-11'),
(102,  57, 1, 1, 1, 1, 60, '2015-03-11'),
(102,  58, 1, 1, 1, 1, 90, '2015-03-11'),
(102,  59, 1, 1, 1, 1, 120, '2015-03-11'),
(102,  60, 1, 1, 1, 1, 150, '2015-03-11'),
(102,  61, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-12'),
(102,  62, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-12'),
(102,  63, 1, 1, 1, 1, 60, '2015-03-12'),
(102,  64, 1, 1, 1, 1, 90, '2015-03-12'),
(102,  65, 1, 1, 1, 1, 120, '2015-03-12'),
(102,  66, 1, 1, 1, 1, 150, '2015-03-12'),
(102,  67, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2015-03-13'),
(102,  68, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, '2015-03-13'),
(102,  69, 1, 1, 1, 1, 60, '2015-03-13'),
(102,  70, 1, 1, 1, 1, 90, '2015-03-13'),
(102,  71, 1, 1, 1, 1, 120, '2015-03-13'),
(102,  72, 1, 1, 1, 1, 150, '2015-03-13');
```

After running the selection query, the result is as follows:

```
select * from TEST_ACTIVITY ORDER BY pet_id, date, start_time;

| pet_id | simple_sleep_time | deep_sleep_time | mild_movement_time | moderate_movement_time | severe_movement_time | start_time | date       |
+--------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------+----------------------+------------+------------+
|    100 |                 1 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-10 |
|    100 |                 2 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-10 |
|    100 |                 3 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         60 | 2015-03-10 |
|    100 |                 4 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         90 | 2015-03-10 |
|    100 |                 5 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        120 | 2015-03-10 |
|    100 |                 6 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        150 | 2015-03-10 |
|    100 |                 7 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-11 |
|    100 |                 8 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-11 |
|    100 |                 9 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         60 | 2015-03-11 |
|    100 |                10 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         90 | 2015-03-11 |
|    100 |                11 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        120 | 2015-03-11 |
|    100 |                12 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        150 | 2015-03-11 |
|    100 |                13 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-12 |
|    100 |                14 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-12 |
|    100 |                15 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         60 | 2015-03-12 |
|    100 |                16 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         90 | 2015-03-12 |
|    100 |                17 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        120 | 2015-03-12 |
|    100 |                18 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        150 | 2015-03-12 |
|    100 |                19 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-13 |
|    100 |                20 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-13 |
|    100 |                21 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         60 | 2015-03-13 |
|    100 |                22 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         90 | 2015-03-13 |
|    100 |                23 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        120 | 2015-03-13 |
|    100 |                24 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        150 | 2015-03-13 |
|    101 |                25 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-10 |
|    101 |                26 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-10 |
|    101 |                27 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         60 | 2015-03-10 |
|    101 |                28 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         90 | 2015-03-10 |
|    101 |                29 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        120 | 2015-03-10 |
|    101 |                30 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        150 | 2015-03-10 |
|    101 |                31 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-11 |
|    101 |                32 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-11 |
|    101 |                33 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         60 | 2015-03-11 |
|    101 |                34 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         90 | 2015-03-11 |
|    101 |                35 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        120 | 2015-03-11 |
|    101 |                36 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        150 | 2015-03-11 |
|    101 |                37 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-12 |
|    101 |                38 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-12 |
|    101 |                39 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         60 | 2015-03-12 |
|    101 |                40 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         90 | 2015-03-12 |
|    101 |                41 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        120 | 2015-03-12 |
|    101 |                42 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        150 | 2015-03-12 |
|    101 |                43 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-13 |
|    101 |                44 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-13 |
|    101 |                45 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         60 | 2015-03-13 |
|    101 |                46 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         90 | 2015-03-13 |
|    101 |                47 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        120 | 2015-03-13 |
|    101 |                48 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        150 | 2015-03-13 |
|    102 |                49 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-10 |
|    102 |                50 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-10 |
|    102 |                51 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         60 | 2015-03-10 |
|    102 |                52 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         90 | 2015-03-10 |
|    102 |                53 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        120 | 2015-03-10 |
|    102 |                54 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        150 | 2015-03-10 |
|    102 |                55 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-11 |
|    102 |                56 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-11 |
|    102 |                57 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         60 | 2015-03-11 |
|    102 |                58 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         90 | 2015-03-11 |
|    102 |                59 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        120 | 2015-03-11 |
|    102 |                60 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        150 | 2015-03-11 |
|    102 |                61 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-12 |
|    102 |                62 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-12 |
|    102 |                63 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         60 | 2015-03-12 |
|    102 |                64 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         90 | 2015-03-12 |
|    102 |                65 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        120 | 2015-03-12 |
|    102 |                66 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        150 | 2015-03-12 |
|    102 |                67 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |          0 | 2015-03-13 |
|    102 |                68 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         30 | 2015-03-13 |
|    102 |                69 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         60 | 2015-03-13 |
|    102 |                70 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |         90 | 2015-03-13 |
|    102 |                71 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        120 | 2015-03-13 |
|    102 |                72 |               1 |                  1 |                      1 |                    1 |        150 | 2015-03-13 |
+--------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------+----------------------+------------+------------+
```

I want to first calculate each pet's daily score using this formula:

```
 score = SUM(severe_movement_time) + SUM(moderate_movement_time) + SUM(mild_movement_time) + SUM(simple_sleep_time),
```

and then decide each pet's rank based on its score. Important note: a pet's one-day activity data expands across two days. For example, for pet_id = 100, the activity data of 2015-03-11 satisfies the following condition:

```
(date = DATE_SUB(DATE('2015-03-11'), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND start_time >= 120 AND start_time <= 150) OR (date = DATE('2015-03-11') AND start_time <= (120 - 30) AND start_time >= 0 ).
```

Namely, the activity data of 2015-03-11 contains the following 6 entries:

```
date=2015-03-10, start_time=120
date=2015-03-10, start_time=150
date=2015-03-11, start_time=0
date=2015-03-11, start_time=30
date=2015-03-11, start_time=60
date=2015-03-11, start_time=90
```

By using the following query, I can do it for one day, 2015-03-11.

```
SELECT pet_id, date, score, rank
FROM 
(
    SELECT scoreFinder.pet_id, scoreFinder.date, scoreFinder.score, @prev := @curr, @curr := score, @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank 
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT pet_id, date, (COALESCE(SUM(severe_movement_time), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(moderate_movement_time), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(mild_movement_time), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(simple_sleep_time), 0)) score 
            FROM TEST_ACTIVITY  
            WHERE ((date = DATE_SUB(DATE('2015-03-11'), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND start_time >= 120 AND start_time <= 150) OR 
                   (date = DATE('2015-03-11') AND start_time <= (120 - 30) AND start_time >= 0 ))       
            GROUP BY pet_id 
        ) scoreFinder, (SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 0) rank 
    ORDER BY score DESC
) rankFinder
```

My question is how to write a single query to calculate the scores and rankings for several consecutive days, for example, for 3 days (start_date=2015-03-11, end_date=2015-03-13). The expected result is listed below.

```
| pet_id | date       | score | rank |
+--------+------------+-------+------+
|    102 | 2015-03-11 | 351   | 1    |
|    101 | 2015-03-11 | 207   | 2    |
|    100 | 2015-03-11 | 63    | 3    |
|    102 | 2015-03-12 | 387   | 1    |
|    101 | 2015-03-12 | 243   | 2    |
|    100 | 2015-03-12 | 99    | 3    |
|    102 | 2015-03-13 | 423   | 1    |
|    101 | 2015-03-13 | 279   | 2    |
|    100 | 2015-03-13 | 135   | 3    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution -- the basic idea here is to generate the date range in a subquery and then join it with the TEST_ACTIVITY table:

```
SELECT scores.*,
       @rank := IF(@prev = date, @rank + 1, 1) AS rank,
       @prev := date
FROM   (SELECT pet_id,
               dates.date,
               ( Coalesce(Sum(severe_movement_time), 0)
                 + Coalesce(Sum(moderate_movement_time), 0)
                 + Coalesce(Sum(mild_movement_time), 0)
                 + Coalesce(Sum(simple_sleep_time), 0) ) score
        FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT date
                FROM   TEST_ACTIVITY
                WHERE  date >= '2015-03-11'
                       AND date <= '2015-03-13'
                ORDER  BY date) dates
               JOIN TEST_ACTIVITY t
                 ON ( ( t.date = Date_sub(Date(dates.date), INTERVAL 1 day)
                        AND t.start_time >= 120
                        AND t.start_time <= 150 )
                       OR ( t.date = Date(dates.date)
                            AND t.start_time <= ( 120 - 30 )
                            AND t.start_time >= 0 ) )
        GROUP  BY dates.date,
                  t.pet_id
        ORDER  BY dates.date,
                  score DESC) scores,
       (SELECT @prev := NULL,
               @rank := 0) rank;
```

Results on your test data:

```
pet_id  date    score   rank    @prev := date
102 2015-03-11  351 1   2015-03-11
101 2015-03-11  207 2   2015-03-11
100 2015-03-11  63  3   2015-03-11
102 2015-03-12  387 1   2015-03-12
101 2015-03-12  243 2   2015-03-12
100 2015-03-12  99  3   2015-03-12
102 2015-03-13  423 1   2015-03-13
101 2015-03-13  279 2   2015-03-13
100 2015-03-13  135 3   2015-03-13
```